# Select CheckBox of all ListViewItem

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onclicklistener

I got a `ListActivity` with list items I've created. Each item got a `CheckBox` in it. In addition, the layout got a button which is suppose to simply check all the check boxes, yet it's not working even though the `OnClickListener` of the button is being called.

This a method called from the list adapter:

```
    public void ChangeAllCheckStatus(boolean checked)
    {
        synchronized (items)
        {
            for (ItemData item : items)
            {
                item.checked= checked;
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And this is the `getView` method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
        {
            vi = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.myItem, null);
        }
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.firstText);
        TextView addressTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.secondText);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.the_checkBox);
        nameTextView.setText(items.get(position).string1);
        addressTextView.setText(items.get(position).string2);
        cb.setSelected(items.get(position).checked);
        return vi;
    }
```

Is there something wrong with how I'm trying to check all the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 listItem = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
```

is wrong. You shouldn't access the `ListView`'s items directly. You should be encapsulate the checked status  of every single item in the dataset, and let `getView` make its work.

Assuming that you have a `boolean status;` member in your `ListView`'s item, you could add a method in your adapter,

```
public void checkAll() {
  synchronized(items) {
    for (Item item : items) {
       item.status = true;
    }
  }
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Edit:

> It got an adapter which extends BaseAdapter which also receives 2
>   arrays of strings as the values. It creates the view at a specific
>   position simply by setting 2 text boxes with the corresponding values
>   from these 2 arrays.

Instead of having two arrays, you could use a small class which encapsulates the information you need. E.g

```
public class Item {
  public String mFirstString; 
  public String mSecondString;  
  public boolean mStatus;
}
```

and feed the `BaseAdapter` with a collection of this class. E.g

```
ArrayList<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

getItem will return `mItem.get(position)`, and on getView you'll set the text and the checkbox. E.g.

```
 Item item = getItem(position);
 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.the_checkBox);
 cb.setChecked(item.mStatus);
```

Comment: I actually didn't even know you can create a class for the item.. I'm simply inflating a layout to create the view for the item.

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using ?

Comment: It got an adapter which extends BaseAdapter which also receives 2 arrays of strings as the values. It creates the view at a specific position simply by setting 2 text boxes with the corresponding values from these 2 arrays.

Comment: First of all the way you do it in your answer is so much better than I did. It now taught me a whole new way of dealing with ListViews. Regarding this specific case, I see the code does what I expect it to do and it does create the views I want with the boolean values I need, but the checkbox itself for some reason doesn't get updated.. when I try to select all, the checkbox remains off, even though I debuged and saw that the setselected get true as its value.

Comment: would you mind updating the question with the changes you made ?

Comment: why are you using `setSelected` ?

Comment: That was indeed the problem.. what's the difference between selected and checked?

Comment: setSelected is a method of View which is not related to the checked status of a CompoundButton. Simple answer is they are completely unrelated

Comment: Thank you very much... that was one of the more productive answers I learned from.

Answer (score 2):

You don't fetch the views from an adapter. The `ListView` does that.

Instead you can loop them via a `ListView` like this:

```
ListView lv;
int itemCount = lv.getCount();
for (int i=0; i<itemCount; ++i) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.the_checkBox);
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Will it then iterate over ALL items and check their boxes or will it do it for the visible items only?

Comment: @YonatanNir all the items. Reading the documentation helps, you know.

Comment: @YonatanNir I can imagine why you'd ask this. Because checked positions don't get saved, the adapter will set them to their default once you scroll. However saving the checked state for each position is a whole 'nother question.

Comment: This answer almost works... for some reason the last item (meaning the lv.getChildAt(i) when i is the last one in the iteration) always returns null.. have any idea why?

Comment: @YonatanNir does your `ListView` contain a footer or a header?

Comment: No. It just got an adapter which extends BaseAdapter which also receives 2 arrays of strings as the values. It creates the view at a specific position simply by setting 2 text boxes with the corresponding values from these 2 arrays.

Comment: @YonatanNir weird. Adapter's `getView` implementation and the place where you set your items would be useful to find the problem here.